# Default GCC flags

Tags: c, gcc

I am writing a simple C program that I'm supposed to attack with a buffer overflow.  So, I don't want any flags used when compiling.  How do I eliminate the default flags from being used?

```
# readelf -p .GCC.command.line stack

String dump of section '.GCC.command.line':
  [     0]  stack.c
  [     8]  -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2
  [    1c]  -mtune=generic
  [    2b]  -march=i486
  [    37]  -frecord-gcc-switches
  [    4d]  -fstack-protector
```

Comment: You can usually counter flags with anti-flags... check the docs.

Comment: "don't want any flags used" is pretty much a meaningless concept. For example, optimization runs from -O0 to -O3, but there's no escaping having a flag there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only two options there that make any sense to override are `-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE` and `-fstack-protector`, so just include `-U_FORTIFY_SOURCE` and `-fnostack-protector`, and they're effectively "gone".

You can't compile for "no architecture" (`march`), and getting rid of `mtune` is similarly meaningless. GCC has to build code for *something*. You're already about as generic as you can get there.

`-frecord-gcc-switches`, well, without that, you wouldn't know what switches were included in the first place, but if you really want to get rid of it, just use `-fnorecord-gcc-switches`.

[`-f*` options](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Code-Gen-Options.html) are mostly boolean flags, so you can almost always turn them off by adding `no` at the front as I've done above.

Comment: I think `-U_FORTIFY_SOURCE` would be preferred.

Answer (score 2):

What about doing something like

```
gcc -dumpspecs > myspecs.txt
```

Edit the specs as needed and compile with

```
gcc -specs=myspecs.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

If looks like your problem is that you're using a vendor/distro-provided gcc that's been hacked to turn on various security-related options by default. The other answers have tips for how to undo the changes, but if you want to work with a pristine, default gcc, it might be best to compile your own and install it in a non-default notation, and use it for your experimentation.